# How to view the vertex color of softbody distortion?

Tags: soft-body, dynamic-paint

I saw a tutorial on destroying a car and realized that the tutor used a way to visualize the softbody distortion of the mesh.
example gif:

[image]

video reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ff7-4ob62U

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve with the addon "tension map"

link addon tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G8SkBQngvw

[image]

[image]